# How can Update Fragment in Viewpager Dyanamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, material-design, fragmentstatepageradapter

the scenario is, I have two fragments, one is Category List and another fragment is Product list w.r.t category list, so when I click on Item into the category list, then I want to send selected value to the Product List Fragment then how can this possible please help me.

Comment: post your code too, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use "Broadcast Receiver" to receive data or to tell fragment to update data

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus library. It is a good library for notifying and passing data from fragment to fragment.
Check it here: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is to use Google Architecture components, ViewModel and LiveData. In this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing), you'll find an example that will help you to archive what you want.